# iOS Multitasking Gestures - disable / enable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Does anyone know of any code to enable or mainly disable the Multitasking Gestures in iOS 4.3?

Answer (score 2):

There is no public API to access or set this information.

Answer (score 1):

I think the multitasking support is enabled/disabled from the Settings app, it doesn't look like there is support to change this setting programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You would **probably** access this via `UIDevice* device = [UIDevice currentDevice];`... but [as you can see from the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html), there is no access to anything like this property.