# Is it possible to override multitask gestures in an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I have a couple of apps for kids out on the AppStore, and the new multitask gestures (on iPad) are getting triggered by kids all the time, which is not good.

Is it possible to override those gestures in the app to catch them before the OS sees them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Multitasking Gestures - disable / enable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263558/ios-multitasking-gestures-disable-enable)

Comment: Close, maybe, but definitely not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API to access those gestures, plus they're managed by the SpringBoard itself. So, no, without a jailbroken iPhone, you can't override them. The user can enable/disable them in the Settings app, though.