# Disable 4 finger gestures of iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, gestures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS Multitasking Gestures - disable / enable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263558/ios-multitasking-gestures-disable-enable)

Im busy making a iPad app where you sometimes need 4 fingers, but with the new iOS its know possible to have the 4 finger gestures (to close, multitasking, switching app), but i want disable them.

Possible?

Thnks already

Comment: Yes this is possible, but not programmatically.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263558/ios-multitasking-gestures-disable-enable